# Why does Instagram on Android not accept Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE

Tags: android-intent, instagram, instagram-api

The instagram app has support for multiple photo posts:
https://help.instagram.com/269314186824048
http://blog.instagram.com/post/157572774352/170222-multiple

Instagram documents how to share a photo to the Instagram app using intents here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/

But it appears to not accept ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE, so will only accept a single photo.

Android documents this intent and an example of how to receive it here:
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html#handling-content
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE

Is there a particular reason why the Instagram App might not want to accept multiple photos shared with it?

Comment: This question must be answered by an Instagram API team. Also were you able to return back to the Android App after the Share was completed?

Comment: Similar question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460270/posting-multiple-images-to-instagram-using-intents

Comment: @NickBroon Have you solved this problem? There's application named Buffer, they somehow managed to open Instagram with Intent on screen with adding more photos. However, if we use documented code, we cannot post multi-picture post.